# Wrong array item after using orderby filter AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an app that works well displaying a list of students. When you click on each name, it displays more info about that particular student. However, if I change the order of names through select options or search, wrong student info is displayed.
Here is my view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="expression" placeholder="Search Student" />
<div class="select">
<span>Sort By: &nbsp;</span>
<select ng-model="order" ng-show="students.length > 0">
    <option selected value="name">Name A-Z</option>
    <option value="-name">Name Z-A</option>
    <option value="room">Room (first to last)</option>
    <option value="-room">Room (last to first)</option>           
</select>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="student in students | orderBy: order | filter:expression">        

<div class="info">
    <div class="img">
        <img ng-src="{{student.image}}">
    </div>
    <h2 style="color: #007acc;"> Student Details For:</h2>
    <hr>
    <h2>{{student.name}}</h2>
    <a ng-href="#!/students/{{$index}}"><button>View Student 
    Details</button></a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my Js:

```
var data = [
{
    name: "Andrea Toe",
    sex: "Female",
    room: 12,
    cell: "076 861 6184",
    image: "images/female.jpg",
    checkin: "June 2016"
},
{
    name: "John Doe",
    sex: "Female",
    room: 3,          
    cell: "063 961 7190",
    image: "images/lebo.jpg",
    checkin: "01 Feb 2018"      
},
{
    name: "James Drew",
    sex: "Male",
    room: 1,
    cell: "076 910 3069",
    image: "images/male.jpeg",
    checkin: "01 Feb 2018"
 }
];
app.controller("studentsCtrl", function($scope){
$scope.students = data;
});
app.controller('studentInfoCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 
function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.info = data[$routeParams.id];
}]);
```

What should I do to get it to display correct info even after using search filter or reordering using oderBy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching and sorting are working fine for me:

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Andrea Toe",
    sex: "Female",
    room: 12,
    cell: "076 861 6184",
    image: "images/female.jpg",
    checkin: "June 2016"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "John Doe",
    sex: "Female",
    room: 3,
    cell: "063 961 7190",
    image: "images/lebo.jpg",
    checkin: "01 Feb 2018"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "James Drew",
    sex: "Male",
    room: 1,
    cell: "076 910 3069",
    image: "images/male.jpeg",
    checkin: "01 Feb 2018"
  }
];
app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("studentsCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.students = data;
});
app.controller('studentInfoCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.info = data.filter(function(d){
      return d.id == $routeParams.id;
    })[0];
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="studentsCtrl">

  <input type="text" ng-model="expression" placeholder="Search Student" />
  <div class="select">
    <span>Sort By: &nbsp;</span>
    <select ng-model="order" ng-show="students.length > 0">
      <option selected value="name">Name A-Z</option>
      <option value="-name">Name Z-A</option>
      <option value="room">Room (first to last)</option>
      <option value="-room">Room (last to first)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="student in students | filter:expression | orderBy: order ">

    <div class="info">
      <!-- <div class="img">
        <img ng-src="{{student.image}}">
      </div> -->
      <h2 style="color: #007acc;"> Student Details For:</h2>
      <hr>
      <h2>{{student.name}}</h2>
      <a ng-href="#!/students/{{student.id}}"><button>View Student 
    Details</button></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My question is not on filtering or sorting. That works fine. My problem is that after sorting or filtering, when you click on a student name, it displays info of a wrong student. Eg. when you search for John Doe and click on his name, it displays info for Andrea Toe instead.

Comment: Use `student.id` for routing instead of `$index`. because it changes how your ng-repeat data is rendered and it do not change data in your actual array.

Comment: If I replace $index with student.id like this: `<a ng-href="#!/students/{{student.id}}"><button>View Student 
    Details</button></a>` it stops working, it doesn't route.

Comment: have you added id in your student data. also on routed page to retrieve student from data use filter as in code.

Comment: Is there a way of adding id: dynamically in the array because if I use a delete function and remove an item, then it starts showing wrong student info again? Here is my delete function: `$scope.remove=function(item){ var index=$scope.students.indexOf(item) $scope.students.splice(index,1); };`

Comment: simply iterate over students array and assign ids. e.g. `$scope.students.forEach( function(d, i){ d.id = i+1; });`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because, when creating the link to the "student details", you use the `$index` scope variable.

This `$index` is introduced by the `ng-repeat` directive and will represent the:

> iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)

(from the [documentation linked here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat))

In short, the `$index` you use to uniquely identify a student when building the corresponding link to their details page **depends entirely on its position in the page**. It does not at all identify the resource itself!

What you could do is have an `id` property assigned to each student along with their name, sex etc., like so:

```
var data = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Andrea Toe",
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: "John Doe",
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "James Drew",
}];
```

And simply refer to that newly introduced property in the urls you create!

```
<a ng-href="#!/students/{{ student.id }}"><button>View Student Details</button></a>
```

Comment: Ok, I will. Is there a way of adding id: dynamically in the array because if I use a delete function and remove an item, then it starts showing wrong student info again? `$scope.remove=function(item){ 
  var index=$scope.students.indexOf(item)
  $scope.students.splice(index,1);     
};`